# How to get full tree node path in reverse order in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, tree, recursive-query

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE descriptor_value (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    value varchar(250),
    parent_id bigint
) ;
```

`id` column is the primary key.

And I have three rows

```
id | value | parent_id
----------------------
1  | foo   | null
2  | bar   | 1
3  | baz   | 2
```

And I need to create view that will show full path of `every` node in reverse order. For example, if we consider only baz there must be the following output:

```
child_id | parent_id | level
----------------------------
 3       | 3         | 1
 3       | 2         | 2    
 3       | 1         | 3
```

Could anyone say how to do it in PgSQL 12?

Comment: How do this show the *full path*?

Comment: @GMB I am migrating one project from oracle to pgsql so I only do tables and nothing more. They named it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want to traverse the tree from the leafs to the node(s). That would be:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select id child_id, id parent_id, 1 lvl, parent_id real_parent_id
    from descriptor_value dv
    where not exists (select 1 from descriptor_value dv1 where dv1.parent_id = dv.id)
    union all
    select c.child_id, dv.id parent_id, lvl + 1, dv.parent_id
    from cte c
    inner join descriptor_value dv on dv.id = c.real_parent_id
)
select child_id, parent_id, lvl from cte order by lvl
```

The anchor of the recursive query starts from rows that are not parent of any other node. Then we climb up the tree, incrementing `lvl` at each step, until we reach the root.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f69ffde1c3fed25e1ea8d3ce6fd70e8e)**:

```
child_id | parent_id | lvl
-------: | --------: | --:
       3 |         3 |   1
       3 |         2 |   2
       3 |         1 |   3
```

---

If you want to start from *any* node, then it is even simpler: we just need to change the definition of the anchor:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select id child_id, id parent_id, 1 lvl, parent_id real_parent_id
    from descriptor_value dv
    union all
    select c.child_id, dv.id parent_id, lvl + 1, dv.parent_id
    from cte c
    inner join descriptor_value dv on dv.id = c.real_parent_id
)
select child_id, parent_id, lvl from cte order by child_id, lvl
```

**[Yields](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=37fd545843300851662ea459830c707b)**:

```
child_id | parent_id | lvl
-------: | --------: | --:
       1 |         1 |   1
       2 |         2 |   1
       2 |         1 |   2
       3 |         3 |   1
       3 |         2 |   2
       3 |         1 |   3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select dv.id, dv.value, dv.parent_id, dv.parent_id as root, 1 as lev,
             dv.id::text as path
      from descriptor_value dv
      where dv.parent_id is null
      union all
      select dv.id, dv.value, dv.parent_id, cte.root, lev + 1,
             cte.path || '-->' || (dv.id::text)
      from cte join
           descriptor_value dv
           on dv.parent_id = cte.id
    )
select cte.id, cte.value, cte.parent_id, cte.root, lev,
       max(lev) over (partition by cte.root) - lev + 1 as level
from cte
order by root, lev;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f76d3a7a0a568e951c3fe9583204c724) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Why do you use `value` column?

Comment: @iJava . . . This doesn't "use" `value`.  It simply keeps it.  You can select whatever columns you want for the final result set.

Comment: Unfortunately the result is quite different from the one I showed in my question. Please, see @GMB answer my comment.